# How to Enable Customer Ajax Login / Register Captcha in Magento 2 Not Working

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, captcha

**Now i am trying add CAPTCHA is Customer Configuration but CAPTCHA is not shown at ajax Login/register form.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to clear Magento Cache and Browser cache?

Comment: now already clear cache..

Comment: The other forms are showing captcha or not?

Comment: yes simple register from captcha  working but ajax login and registration not working.

Comment: Where can I test Ajax register form? I didn't find a way to test this case.

Comment: Any other solution in your end..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67770/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-ravindrasinh-zala).

Comment: If you can customize https://magecomp.com/magento-2-google-recaptcha.html